# java stop a timer in a task

Tags: java, timer, task

In Java, I am using the following code for a Timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer("WeatherUpdate");
MyTask t = new MyTask();
timer.schedule(t, 10000, 10000);

class MyTask extends TimerTask 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        PlaceWeatherObjectsInSpace();
    }
}
```

If at a later date, I would like to stop this timer, what is the best way to code this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t.cancel();` where `t` is your `TimerTask`

OR

```
class MyTask extends TimerTask 
{

    public void run() 
    {
        if(taskHasToEnd) { //taskHasToEnd can be any boolean expression comparing current date with the 'date' at which the task should end
            cancel();
        }
        PlaceWeatherObjectsInSpace();
    }
}
```